# Optimize MySQL order by query

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have the following query to get the most viewed articles that submitted in last month for example.

```
explain 
SELECT * 
FROM article 
WHERE date > 1315391769 
ORDER BY views DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

how do I choose the right index for this query? or how do I re-write it to avoid scanning a lot of rows or file sorting?

This is the table scheme with the current indexes I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `date` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `views` (`views`),
  KEY `date_2` (`date`,`views`),
  KEY `views_2` (`views`,`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=200003 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `article`
-- 

INSERT INTO `article` VALUES (1, 'title test113', 'test body118', 1317912183, 5017);
INSERT INTO `article` VALUES (2, 'title test193', 'test body193', 1313441124, 5943);
INSERT INTO `article` VALUES (3, 'title test112', 'test body116', 1312773586, 653);
INSERT INTO `article` VALUES (4, 'title test378', 'test body374', 1316786646, 4589);
INSERT INTO `article` VALUES (5, 'title test335', 'test body3310', 1319173694, 6224);
```

Notice: I also tried mysql date instead of Unix timestamp but I got the same result.

This is the output of EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  article     range   date,date_2     date    4   NULL    107245  Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: @ I posted only 5 rows as sample.

Comment: what is an int(32) ? is it some kinda signed bigger int ? and for that matter, what is an int(11) ?? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: It should be 11 not 32. I already change it to MySQL time and MySQL datetime and I got the same result.

Comment: EXPLAIN is rather useless when the table has so few rows. Try having a few thousands or tens of thousands.

Comment: @ypercube there are more than 200000 rows

Answer (score 1):

A single key `date_2` (`date`,`views`) should give optimal performance for the query in question. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) I don't think the other indexes are going to help. Since the query is so simple I can't think of any other optimization!

Comment: No, user_ksa is correct. Either `(date)` or `(views)` index can be used.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of queries, only either `(date)` or `(views)` index can be used and not the compound `(date,views)`. What MySQL chooses to use may or may not be optimal. And what is optimal for February may not be for April data!

- You can try forcing one of the two and measure preformance.
- You could add a calculated column with `Year-Month` data, using a `CHAR(6)` like `201104` for April 2011 (that column can be updated using INSERT and UPDATE triggers) or an `int` like `24136` (24136 = 2011*12 + 4).

Then your condition would be:

```
WHERE YearMonth = '201109'            --- for September
```

or

```
WHERE YearMonth = 2011*12+9
```

and a `(YearMonth, views)` index could be used.

Answer (score 1):

By forcing index, it is achieved.

```
explain 
SELECT * 
FROM article force index (`views`)
WHERE date>=1315391768  
ORDER BY views DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Explain plan:

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table"     "type"       "possible_keys"    "key"   "key_len"     "ref" "rows"  "Extra"
 "1"    "SIMPLE"       "article"    "index"           \N           "views"    "4"           \N  "5" "Using where"
```